# Time Zone по координатам

Tags: yandex-maps-api, timezone

Мне необходим функционал для определение временной зоны (timezone) по местоположению пользователя. Такой функционал есть у Google Maps, но в Yandex Maps я такого функционала не обнаружил.

Это связано с тем, что мне нужно в мобильном приложении понимать в какой временной зоне сейчас находится пользователь, чтобы отразить ему в его времени необходимые данные.

Comment: В API Яндекс Карт подобных методов нет. Вам нужно искать стороннее решение.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, Александр. Печально. Я надеялся. что данный функционал был разработан в последнее время или планируется к разработке.